# How to use Bot top role position command in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I want code a bot when ctx.author role position is lower than bot role , ctx.author gets error And can not use that command for example:
I coded This
(client is bot object)

```
@client.command()
async def ab(ctx):
    if client.top_role.position > ctx.author.top_role.position:
        await ctx.send('Error!')
        return
    staff
    .
    .
    .
```

But There is no Attribute named top_role for bot object.
Is There other way for do something like that?Any Idea?

Also I tried with get_user(Id), but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@client.command()
async def ab(ctx):
    if ctx.guild.me.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
        await ctx.send('Error!')
        return
```

Comment: Worked!Thanks✨